# Does a clean proof exist of why $\mbox {dim range}T=\mbox {dim range}T^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Does a clean proof exist of why $\mbox {dim range}T=\mbox {dim range}T^*$?

Here $T^*$ is the adjoint or the conjugate transpose. This is assuming we have a finite dimensional vector space such that $T \in L(V)$. The proof I have involves the dimension of the null of $T^*$.

Comment: It is false that the range of $T$ is the same as the range of $T^*$.

Comment: Do you intend for $T^* \in L(V^*)$ to be the adjoint (conjugate transpose)?  If so, then please edit the question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection onto $\operatorname{range}T$. Then $PT=T$. Take adjoints: $T^*P=T^*$. Hence $\operatorname{rank}T^*\le \operatorname{rank}P=\operatorname{rank}T$. The reverse inequality follows from $T=T^{**}$.

Comment: BTW, this does not require the ambient space to be finite-dimensional; works in any Hilbert space.